# Bouncing Ball Distance

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that allow me to enter a height of a ball to be dropped and put in the number of bounces and give me the total distance. I am having trouble with my equation and see some in-sight please.

```
h = int(input("Enter hieght"))
b = int(input("Enter Number of Bounces"))


for eachPass in range (b):
    d = h * 0.6

    if b >= 1:
        bounce1 = h + d
        if b >= 2:
            bounce2 = (d * 0.6) + bounce1 + d

        print (bounce2)
```

Comment: Are you not getting what you expected when you printed `bounce2`?

Comment: Did you perhaps want `range(b) + 1`? I don't believe `range(b)` will actually include `b`.

Comment: I get the it to go through the number of time I have selected, but it doesn't change the bounce distance

Comment: What did you enter for `b`?

Comment: You have a loop that just does the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Instead of using `b` inside the loop, I think you want to use `eachPass`.

Comment: And `d` won't ever change because it's always set to be `h*0.6` and `h` never changes.

Comment: eachPass don't work it doesn't have a value

Comment: I believe it is a value.

Comment: sorry, for some reason or another I was thinking you talking about replacing '(b)' with 'eachPass'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't be sure, I believe you want something like this instead

```
h = int(input("Enter height"))
b = int(input("Enter Number of Bounces"))
bounce1 = 0
bounce2 = 0
d = h * 0.6
for eachPass in range(b):
    if eachPass == 1:
        bounce1 = h + d
    if eachPass == 2:
        bounce2 = bounce1 + h + d

print str(bounce2)
```